# how to add css class with javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to print different divs on the same webpage. While I got this functionality working, I want to be able to print my heading, paragraph and div with a class name display_full. I don't want to print div with a class name display_short.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
 <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.display_full {display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <article id="printableArea1">
        <header>
          <h1>Heading 1</h1>
          <p>Some text</p>
          <div class="display_short">This is div 1</div>
  </header>
    <div class="display_full">This is div 2 and I want to print it</div>
  <input value="More" onclick="switchVisible(0, this);" type="button">
  <input onclick="printDiv('printableArea1')" value="Print" type="button">
 </article>
    <article id="printableArea2">
        <header>
          <h1>Heading 2</h1>
          <p>Some text</p>
          <div class="display_short"><p>This is div 1</p></div>
  </header>
    <div class="display_full">This is div 2 and I want to print it</div>
  <input value="More" onclick="switchVisible(1, this);" type="button">
  <input onclick="printDiv('printableArea2')" value="Print" type="button">
 </article>
    
</div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function switchVisible(index, input) {
    var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName('display_short')[index];
    var div2 = document.getElementsByClassName('display_full')[index];
    if (div1) {
        if (div1.style.display == 'none') {
            div1.style.display = 'block';
            div2.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            div1.style.display = 'none';
            div2.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
 console.log(input);
    if (input.value == "More") input.value = "Less";
    else input.value = "More";
}
function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
 

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should think of using CSS media queries instead if older browsers support isn't an issue: `@media print{
    .display_short {
          display: none;   
    }
}`

Comment: I've tried this method, but it doesn't work. I believe that is because I need to use multiple print on the web page, and I'm enabling this functionality with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer:

Use `element.className = "my-class"`.

#### Long(er) answer:

Since `class` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript and earlier versions of JavaScript did not allow accessing a property via the dot operator if the property name is a reserved name (e.g. `element.class`), the property is called `className`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged this jQuery here are some notes in that regard:

Add a class:

```
$('someselector').addClass('classtoadd');
```

Toggle a class:(adds or removes this class if it already exists)

```
$('someselector').toggleClass('classtotoggle');
```

Select a class:

```
$('.classtoselect').css('border','solid 1px lime');
```

Remove selected class(s)

```
$('someselector').removeClass('classtoremove');//remove one

// remove multiple
$('someselector').removeClass('classtoremove removethisclassalso andthisclassaswell');

$('someselector').removeClass(); // all classes removed

var hasAClass = $('someselector').hasClass('someclass');//returns true if it has the class
```

Combine the `.addClass()` with CSS and media and you have it:

CSS:

```
@media print{ .donotprintme { display: none; } }
```

code:

```
$('.display_short').addClass('donotprintme');
```